# Can't get next() after parent() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the next element ('ul') after I traverse up and get a parent.

But I'm getting an error. "object doesn't support property or method next"

```js
var p = $(e.target).parents()[1];
var c = p.next('ul');
```

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
 var c = $(p).next('ul');
```

re-blessing your element into a jQuery object. Btw do you really need to access the dom node instead of keeping it wrapped in the jquery object ? You can access the grandparent using `parent().parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to just use `.parent()` if you're looking for the immediate parent. But if you really want the *grandparent* then use `.eq(1)` instead of `[0]`, as this gives you a plain DOM element, without the benefit of jQuery methods.

```
//looking for the immediate parent?
var p = $(e.target).parent();    //or .parents().first()
var c = p.next('ul');

//looking for the grand parent?
var p = $(e.target).parents().eq(1);
var c = p.next('ul');
```